# Is there a way to retrieve text from a webpage to a TextBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Let say I have a `TextBox1` and a `SaveButton`. A website `"www.example.com/code1.text"` with just a content:

```
303981
```

How to retrieve this 303981 to a TextBox?
Do we need a WebBrowser1?

Please help me I'm self learning and beginner also.

Comment: When you say you have a webpage, is this a web page you’ve created yourself and look how to get a user entered vale in the code behind, or someone else’s web page you’re wanting to scrape data from?  You probably want to edit your question some with the full detail of exactly what your trying to do and what you’ve attempted so far

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`System.Net.WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0) type.

```
Using wc As New WebClient()
    TextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString("www.example.com/code1.text")
End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to place a webbrowser control on your form. I would use  CefSharp for this
(see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6d-AgfFzr70)

then you can do something like:

```
settings = New CefSettings
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com")
```

Which loads google.com, just change it to the page you want to load.

Now check your website and see if you can get that textbox value by javascript from the console (F12). Check the source if you can access it with it's ID or that you need to use it's class.

for example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('textboxclass')[0].value;
```

if you manage to get the right value back in your browser console, you can go ahead in your program and do somethinh like:

```
Dim task As Task(Of JavascriptResponse) = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(code)
```

where code contains your javascript.

you may do something like:

```
task.ContinueWith(

Sub(t)
            Try
                If t.IsFaulted = False And t.Result IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim response = t.Result 'Error: Result is not a member of Task' 
                    If response.Success And response.Result IsNot Nothing Then
                        taskResult = response.Result
                    Else
                        taskResult = "bad result"
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Dbg("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exception: " & ex.ToString)
                taskResult = ex.ToString
            End Try
        End Sub)
```

to get the result in a string.